# Centering grid items in a 12 column CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I love using CSS grid but can’t for the life of me figure this one out – I have a random number of images which will be inserted into a CSS grid container. Rather than left alignment, as below, I would like central alignment of grid items with the 12 columns.

```
.section-images {
  grid-gap: var(--page-margins);
  grid-column: span 12;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.section-image {
  grid-column: span 4;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

So I would like this below, instead of the above...

[image]

Because there may be 5 images, 6 images, 13 etc. it needs to be automatic – I’m sure there’s an easy way to do this?

[image]

So if they were multiline, you’d have this:

[image]

Many thanks,

Simon

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Thanks have amended

Comment: Is there a reason for using CSS Grid rather than Flexbox? If I understand what you are trying to do correctly it looks like you could instead put the images in a flexbox row, with wrapping, and justify-content: center.